# Did Jesus eat with idolaters?

Tags: contradiction, mark, pauline-epistles, idolatry

Paul instructs believers not to eat with certain classes of sinners, including fornicators, drunkards, and idolaters.

> But now I have written unto you not to keep company, if any man that
> is called a brother be a fornicator, or covetous, or an idolater, or a
> railer, or a drunkard, or an extortioner; with such an one no not to
> eat. (1 Corinthians 5:11, KJV)

We know that Jesus ate with sinners.

> And it came to pass, that, as Jesus sat at meat in his house, many
> publicans and sinners sat also together with Jesus and his disciples:
> for there were many, and they followed him. (Mark 2:15, KJV)

But is there any evidence that Jesus' own practice in eating with sinners contrasted with Paul's instruction?  Is it safe to assume that the sinners who ate with Jesus, being among those who claimed to follow God, were not idolaters?

NOTE: A related, but different, question is found [HERE.](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/53020/does-paul-contradict-jesus-by-saying-not-to-eat-with-sinners)

Answer (score 1):

Paul is talking about "*any man that is called a brother*".
He is saying not to associate with so-called Christians that don't actually practice the religion.

Jesus is associating with "*sinners*" that do not pretend to be Christian.

The first is a warning against bringing oneself down.
The second is about helping others up.

Answer (score 0):

> Did Jesus eat with idolaters ?

Technically, no, since there weren't any in Israel, where Christ lived and preached; but that's probably not what you wanted to ask.

The main point of 1 Corinthians 5 is partaking of the Eucharist, not meals in general, as can easily be seen from context (5:7-8, along with 10:16-21 and 11:23-30).

> We know that Jesus ate with sinners.

He did; but He did not invite any such (unrepentant) sinners to partake of His Last Supper, but only His faithful followers and disciples.

Answer (score 0):

#### Did Jesus eat with idolaters?

As Ray Butterworth pointed out, Paul is speaking about "brothers", now-professed Christians, that are not following Jesus' teachings.

As to the question of whether idolaters were present with Jesus in Mark 2:15, we really don't know.

There is a parallel account in Matthew chapter 9. The [study note](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwtsty/40/9#s=10&study=discover&v=40:9:10) from the *New World Translation* mentions the following:

> **sinners:** The Bible shows that all humans are sinners. ([Ro 3:23;](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1001070609/10/0) [5:12](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1001070609/10/1)) Therefore, the term is used here in a more specific way, evidently referring to those who had a reputation for practicing sin, perhaps of a moral or a criminal nature. ([Lu 7:37-39;](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1001070609/11/0) [19:7, 8](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1001070609/11/1)) This term was also used for non-Jewish people and by the Pharisees for Jewish people who did not observe the rabbinic traditions.​—[Joh 9:16,](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1001070609/12/0) [24, 25](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1001070609/12/1).

As the study note points out, the word "sinners" could be just about anyone. Also, take into consideration if someone was an idolator but was not known by anyone, this individual would fall into the category of "sinner".

So while "idolater" is a specific type of sinner, Mark points out that Jesus was eating with "sinners" in general.

[All scripture quotations from the [*New World Translation of the Holy Scriptures* (Study Edition)](https://www.jw.org/en/library/bible/study-bible/books/)]

Answer (score 0):

**Did Jesus eat with idolaters?**

Paul admonishes Christians to avoid company with unrepentant sinners.

1 Corinthians 5:11, KJV

> But now I have written unto you not to keep company, if any man that
> is called a brother be a fornicator, or covetous, or an idolater, or a
> railer, or a drunkard, or an extortioner; with such an one no not to
> eat.

We know that Jesus ate with sinners.

Mark 2:15-17 NASB

> 15 And it *happened that He was reclining at the table in his house,
> and many tax collectors and [a]sinners were [b]dining with Jesus and
> His disciples; for there were many of them, and they were following
> Him.

This annoyed the scribes and the Pharisees causing them to murmur to his disciples.

> 16 When the scribes of the Pharisees saw that He was eating with the
> sinners and tax collectors, they said to His disciples, “Why is He
> eating with tax collectors and sinners?”

On hearing them Jesus replied:

> 17 And hearing this, Jesus *said to them, “It is not those who are
> healthy who need a physician, but those who are sick; I did not come
> to call the righteous, but sinners.”

**Conclusion:**

Paul is urging Christian not to associate with unrepentant sinners, Jesus however did not associate with the Jewish sinners [not Christian] Two tax collectors in the scripture are mentioned that have changed their ways, Matthew and Zacchaeus repented and conformed their ways in such a way that they received forgiveness and Divine blessing.